# Office.js dialog taking up more space than specified in displayDialogAsync options

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, office-dialog-api

[image]I'm using Office.js to display a dialog in an Office add-in. I call the displayDialogAsync function like this:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(`https://localhost:3000/notification.htmlmessage=${message}&icon=${icon}`,{ height: 10, width: 10, displayInIframe: true },function (asyncResult) {
dialog = asyncResult.value;
dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processDialogAlertMessage);});
```

However, the dialog that appears takes up more space than I specified in the displayDialogAsync options. It looks like it occupies 20% of the parent window height and 50% of the parent window width, even though I set both height and width to 10.

Why is the dialog taking up more space than specified, and how can I fix this issue to make the dialog appear with the intended dimensions?

Comment: Are you working with Office on Windows, Office on Mac, or Office on the web? Also, what percentage of the whole device screen is taken up by the dialog?

Comment: A screenshot could help with understanding what is wrong with a dialog window.

Comment: What is your screen resolution?

Comment: I am working with Office on Windows

Comment: My screen resolution is 1920 x 1200.

Answer (score 1):

The **height** property defines the height of the dialog as a percentage of the current display. Defaults to 80%. But the **250px** is the minimum height value.

The **width** property defines the width of the dialog as a percentage of the current display. Defaults to 80%. But the **150px** is the minimum width value.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a security requirement of Office that the dialog must present the major part of the add-in's URL in the title bar, minimum width option cannot be satisficed in your scenario.